# How to pass parameter from Asp.net application to Power BI

Tags: stored-procedures, powerbi, azure-sql-database, multi-tenant, powerbi-desktop

We are having multi tenant web application designed in asp.net mvc. Our database is stored on Azure. We have created security policy in the database so no client can see data of another client, and in every table we have tenant id for each entry.

We have created some dashboards using power bi, data is being accessed using sql stored procedure which has tenant id parameter.for testing purpose i supply tenant id while running dashboards inside power bi desktop. Now we are trying to integrate those dashboards to our web application. for this we have done necessary changes in the web.config file.

Issue is how will we supply tenantID for which user is logged in to power bi so that user can see data for that particular client only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [storage mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-storage-mode) of your report (Imported or DirectQuery) and how it will be integrated in your app ([Embedded API](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics), [Publish to web (public)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) or [Secure embed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-embed-secure)).

If the storage mode is `Imported`, this means that your report contains a copy of the data. The consequence is that you can't query the database and get the data based on the current user, because the copy of the data is one and it is shared with all users, which are looking at your report. So the data should be for all tenants and you must filter it in each users session. The filtering can be made in two ways - by adding a "normal" report level filter or by implementing [Row-level security (RLS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls).

Filtering can be achieved by [passing the filter in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters) or [defining the filter in the embedded configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters). First one can be used with Secure embed, while the later one is applicable when using Embedded API. Note, that `Publish to web` method doesn't support URL filters. Important part is that the filter added this way will be visible in the [Filters pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-report-filter) and the user can modify it or remove it (so it's not a good way to secure your data). If you are embedding the report using the API, you can hide the Filters pane by setting `filterPaneEnabled: false` in the [embed config](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details#settings), but this will also hide all other filters and the end user will be able to slice the data only with the visuals provided by you (e.g. slicers in the report). Also note, that secure embed requires each of the viewers of your report to have Power BI Pro license 
(or if the workspace where you publish the report has a dedicated capacity assigned, i.e. [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) or [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/), a Power BI Free license).

With RLS, you will include all the data for all tenants in your report, and Power BI will filter it for you, so the user will see only the data relevant for his tenant. This can be made it two ways - define a role for each tenant and include your end users in the corresponding role, or [use userprincipalname()](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-username-in-dax-with-row-level-security/) DAX function in your report to filter the data based on the current user.

My recommendation is to use RLS, and the benefit in this case is that there will be a single report to embed and no parameters needs to be passed to it from your app at all.

Comment: Hello Andrey, thanks for quick response. Problem is our database has security policy enabled so that not one client can see data of other client. When we want to execute any script we have to set session context for particular client for which we want to see data. Now in this scenario when passing query in power bi while getting data we need to pass client id so that for that client id we can get data. If i don't set session context while running query it will return no result. so in PowerBI for direct query we have to pass clientId.

Comment: And how exactly you are setting this session context?

Comment: We execute this statement in sql when we want see result of script
EXEC sp_set_session_context @key=N'OwnerID', @value=@OwnerID;

In this @OwnerID is id of client for which we want to see data.

Comment: This is a custom implementation, which can't be directly utilized by Power BI. Even if you managed to pass `OwnerID` value from your app to the report, it will re-execute the stored procedure over and over again, on each interaction with the report, which is at least inefficient. With such implementation the best solution will be to create a separate copy of the report for each of your tenants, where you are importing the data returned from this stored procedure, and based on the current user, embed the appropriate report in your app.

Comment: Oh, that is not good. Can you please explain me why the stored procedure will executed again and again? it would be very helpful. are you suggesting for each owner it will re-execute the stored procedure?

Comment: In the report you can import data for all tenants (not possible with current data layer design), one tenant (but needs separate copies of the report for every tenant), on nothing (i.e. use DirectQuery mode, in which for every interaction with a visual, filtering, etc., a new query will be sent to the database, i.e. the stored procedure will be executed once again).